# Equivalence between two ways of writing a circle in complex numbers

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

In complex analysis, I can write a circle centered at $a $ as $|z-a|=r$ and $z-a=re^{i\theta}$. Assuming the former is true, how can I get to the latter? I realize that the first is true because these are all the complex numbers $r$ away from $z$ and the second is true because of euler's formula. How can I formally prove that having the former gives you the latter?

Comment: All complex numbers can be written as $z=r_ze^{i\theta_z}$ for some non-negative real $r_z$ and real $\theta_z.$ You just need to show that if $|z|=r,$ then $r_z=r.$

Comment: "Assuming the former is true, how can I get to the latter?"  Let $u,v \in \Bbb{R}$ be chosen so that $(z - a) = u + iv$.  Since $|z - a| = r > 0$, you have that $u^2 + v^2 = r^2 \implies \frac{u^2}{r^2} + \frac{v^2}{r^2} = 1.$  This implies that if you let $\theta$ denote the angle made in $\Bbb{R^2}$ between the lines $\overline{(0,0), (1,0)}$ and $\overline{(0,0), (u,v)}.$  Then, $(z - a) = (u + iv) = r[\cos(\theta) + i\sin(\theta)] = re^{i\theta}.$  That is, $\cos(\theta) = \frac{u}{r}$ and $\sin(\theta) = \frac{v}{r}.$